# How to declare 2 modules

Tags: angularjs

Firstly I worked with one module "family" it works fine. and when I added another module "seller" the second work but "family" dosen't work anymore !!!

I think the first controller is erased but the second !!!? and I don't know why ! please help me .

```
angular.module('family', []);

angular.module('family')
    .controller('list', function($scope) {
        $scope.family = "Family 1";
    });





angular.module('seller', []);

angular.module('seller')
    .controller('list', function($scope) {
        $scope.seller = "Seller 1";
    });



angular.module('app',
    [
        'ngRoute',
        'family',
        'seller'
    ]
    );

angular.module('app')
    .config(
        ['$routeProvider',
        function($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider.when('/family', {templateUrl: 'modules/family/views/index.html', controller: 'list'});
            $routeProvider.when('/seller', {templateUrl: 'modules/seller/views/index.html', controller: 'list'});

        }]);
```

Comment: Use different controller names or define just one controller. Angular doesn't know which controller you mean, the one on the family module or on the seller module. It will use the first one it finds.

Comment: thank you very much , I was blocked here for more than 3hours. now I chenged names and this work perfect . thank you @DieterGoetelen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just to close this question , the response of @DieterGoetelen in comments resolve all thinks .

and my new code became :

```
angular.module('family', []);

angular.module('family')
    .controller('family.list', function($scope) {
        $scope.family = "Family 1";
    });





angular.module('seller', []);

angular.module('seller')
    .controller('seller.list', function($scope) {
        $scope.seller = "Seller 1";
    });



angular.module('app',
    [
        'ngRoute',
        'family',
        'seller'
    ]
    );

angular.module('app')
    .config(
        ['$routeProvider',
        function($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider.when('/family', {templateUrl: 'modules/family/views/index.html', controller: 'family.list'});
            $routeProvider.when('/seller', {templateUrl: 'modules/seller/views/index.html', controller: 'seller.list'});

        }]);
```